# DATA_LENGTH_0 in maintenance view

Tags: view, abap

I created a view for a client-independent customizing table. The primary key consists of three components - first one being a secondary key on a check table. It is also used to form subsets of the table data. Altogether, it looks something like this:

```
Column  Key
------  --------
frmd    Secondary check table and Subset
attr1   KEY
attr2   KEY
url
```

But everytime I try to insert a new key combination, the view dumps with **DATA_LENGTH_0 CX_SY_RANGE_OUT_OF_BOUNDS**, because the report tries to access a string. Apparently it is somehow related to the field `generictrp` being set. What does this flag tell me and how do I change it? Also non-key components like url are not being fetched - the column is totally empty.

Modifying the customizing table via transaction SM30 works fine, but I don't want that ugly first column.

- I've tried to recreate the view multiple times and I also compared the settings with existing customizing views.
- Access is set to *read,change, delete and insert*
- Display/Maintenance is allowed
- Selecting everything from the View with `SELECT` works fine

#### EDIT

- Picture 1: what I have
- Picture 2: what I want; without the first key column...

[image]

Comment: Please add a code snippet so that we can reproduce the problem. DATA_LENGTH_0 is about a substring operation with length zero (should be >=1). STRING fields are not supported in table/view maintenance dialogs (SM30).

Comment: What do you mean under *that ugly first column*? Give screenshot and proper statement what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, @SandraRossi. But I' m not able to change the coding itself because it is generated by SAP for the maintenance dialog. Also, I'm not using any string component in my table

Comment: I updated the answer for clarification

Comment: Every time you change Something in a DDIC table or view, eventually its nested structures or used data elements or domains, you **need to regenerate all elements of the dialog** (the best way to be sure is to delete + create again). Did you do it?

Comment: @SandraRossi Do I also need to regenerate the data elements and domains? Because I recreated the view and its customizing table several times already.

Comment: No only the **elements of the dialog** (via the screen where you enter the name of the dialog function group and the screen number(s) of the dialog).

Comment: Based on your screenshots, I understand that you need to create a so-called **maintenance view**; you should let the "ID of insertion machine" column as a key field, but you should define it as a selection column ("S" in one of its attributes).

Comment: @SandraRossi Yes, it is declared like that. Part of the problem seems to be that I am using `integer` as type of my key column.  The report activates flag `generictrp` and tries to calculate a keylen from fields `x_namtab-position + x_namtab-flength` which is 0 in the end. That length is also what causes the DATA_LENGTH_0 short dump.

Comment: @nop maybe using an integer is an issue because in my system, none of the dialogs have an integer key, maybe you can use a Packed number (`select distinct dd03l.inttype from DD03L, tvdir where dd03l.tabname = tvdir.tabname and dd03l.keyflag = 'X'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason I faced this problem, is that I had a foreign key of type `i`. I changed the type to `n` and regenerated everything.

Seems to work for now.